# negative numbers floating point subtraction circuit

Tags: floating, subtraction, circuit

probably wrong place to ask but I will try.
I have to design a circuit that would add/subtract  floating point 
I tried to do it using signed magnitude numbers in IEE 754 standard.
They are quite large so I decided to start with something smaller just to prove the concept.
I found a few algorithms on the net for performing addition and substraction of positive numbers.
Most look like this:
http://meseec.ce.rit.edu/eecc250-winter99/250-1-27-2000.pdf
. 
They do not explain what happens with the sign bit.
Now I'm very confused. According to what I've found on the net there is no difference in performing:

```
A-B and A- (-B)
```

could someone help me with a link where the algorithm is explained in detail?

thanks for all answers
I've found this algebraic explanation useful http://howardhuang.us/teaching/cs231/08-Subtraction.pdf 
 Currently my circuit performs A+B (disregarding sign bit) and A-B just like kfmfe04 wrote. I'm XORing B's input and adding 1 so I getting the result in 2C.
 The second pdf suggests including the sign bit in add/sub operation. I will try this in the morning.
 Having spent so many hours exercising my brain I feel a bit tired and can't think straight. Now I just wonder if I should change my circuit so that:
 The toggle add/sub button still XORs the B [a+(-b)] but also before this part I XORs the mantissas'  with their sign to convert them into 2c. 
This way I could cover the case of negative numbers subtraction (-A)-(-B).
 Sounds to complicated though.

Comment: `A-(-B)` is `A+B` algebraically. "According to what I've found on the net there is no difference" needs some supporting links, quotes or references.  It would help if you could explain where you saw this.

Comment: Did you mean `A - B = A + (-B)`?

Comment: I've found this algebraic explanation useful http://howardhuang.us/teaching/cs231/08-Subtraction.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle is that, internally, you have an addition and a subtraction part. Both routines only work on positive numbers.

Below, `ADD` and `SUB` are used to denote the internal routines. You have to divide the operation into different cases, depending on if the operands are positive or negative:

For addition:

```
pos1 + pos2 => pos1 ADD pos1
pos1 + neg2 => pos1 SUB abs(neg2)
neg1 + pos2 => pos2 SUB abs(neg1)
neg1 + neg2 => - (abs(neg1) ADD abs(neg2))
```

For subtraction:

```
pos1 - pos2 => pos1 SUB pos2
pos1 - neg2 => pos1 ADD abs(neg2)
neg1 - pos2 => - (abs(neg1) ADD pos2)
neg1 - neg2 => abs(neg2) SUB abs(neg1)
```

Of course, you could also simply define "A - B" as "A + -B" and only implement the cases for addition.